# PouchDB and electron (windows env)

Tags: npm, electron, pouchdb

While playing with Electron (under Windows) I tried to use PouchDB. Unfortunately it does not seem to work for me.

In my case package.json looks like this:

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron": "^1.4.12",
    "electron-rebuild": "^1.4.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
...
    "electron-reload": "^0.2.0",
    "pouchdb": "*",
    "pouchdb-adapter-node-websql": "*",
    "pouchdb-find": "*",
...
}
```

and js code itself:

```
var pouch = require('pouchdb');
var db = new pouch('mydb-websql');
console.log(db)
```

Results are similar to following:

```
> PouchDB$5 {   __opts: { name: 'mydb-websql', adapter: 'leveldb' },  
> auto_compaction: undefined,   prefix: '_pouch_',   name:
> 'mydb-websql',   _adapter: 'leveldb',   domain: null,   _events: {},  
> _eventsCount: 0,   _maxListeners: undefined,   taskqueue:    TaskQueue$1 {
>      isReady: false,
>      failed:
>       Error: Error: Could not locate the bindings file. Tried:
>        Ôćĺ c:\learning\electron\node_modules\pouchdb\node_modules\leveldown
> \build\leveldown.node
>        Ôćĺ c:\learning\electron\node_modules\pouchdb\node_modules\leveldown
> \build\Debug\leveldown.node
>        Ôćĺ c:\learning\electron\node_modules\pouchdb\node_modules\leveldown
> \build\Release\leveldown.node
>        Ôćĺ c:\learning\electron\node_modules\pouchdb\node_modules\leveldown
> \out\Debug\leveldown.node
>        Ôćĺ c:\learning\electron\node_modules\pouchdb\node_modules\leveldown
> \Debug\leveldown.node
>        Ôćĺ c:\learning\electron\node_modules\pouchdb\node_modules\leveldown
> \out\Release\leveldown.node
>        Ôćĺ c:\learning\electron\node_modules\pouchdb\node_modules\leveldown
> \Release\leveldown.node
>        Ôćĺ c:\learning\electron\node_modules\pouchdb\node_modules\leveldown
> \build\default\leveldown.node
>        Ôćĺ c:\learning\electron\node_modules\pouchdb\node_modules\leveldown
> \compiled\6.5.0\win32\x64\leveldown.node: unable to import leveldown
>           at requireLeveldown (c:\learning\electron\node_modules\pouchdb\li b\index.js:5173:12)
>           at PouchDB$5.LevelDownPouch (c:\learning\electron\node_modules\po uchdb\lib\index.js:5373:17)
>           at new PouchDB$5 (c:\learning\electron\node_modules\pouchdb\lib\i ndex.js:2753:36)
>           at Object.<anonymous> (c:\learning\electron\main.js:6:10)
>           at Module._compile (module.js:556:32)
>           at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:565:10)
>           at Module.load (module.js:473:32)
>           at tryModuleLoad (module.js:432:12)
>           at Function.Module._load (module.js:424:3)
>           at loadApplicationPackage (C:\Users\adam\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modu
> les\electron\dist\resources\default_app.asar\main.js:280:12),
>      queue: [] },   adapter: 'leveldb' }
```

When I use websql adapter results are even I would say worse:

```
App threw an error during load
Error: Invalid Adapter: websql
    at new PouchDB$5 (c:\learning\electron\node_modules\pouchdb\lib\index.j
s:2745:11)
    at Object.<anonymous> (c:\learning\electron\main.js:6:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:556:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:565:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:473:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:432:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:424:3)
    at loadApplicationPackage (C:\Users\adam\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\el
ectron\dist\resources\default_app.asar\main.js:280:12)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\adam\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\electr
on\dist\resources\default_app.asar\main.js:322:5)
    at Module._compile (module.js:556:32)
```

I must admit that I tried to rebuild everything, i tried all adapters with no good outcome. I tried to install sqlite3 additionally and failed again.

Do you perhaps have any other ideas what can go wrong with it or where I may expect my mistake?

---

I tried the same code under linux with and without adapter with failure. I think it does not depend on os

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the issue. The problem was OS related and it all was around recompiling sqlite3. Actually i needed to add windows toolkit and set path to python later (i read it from errors). I figure it out after checking that under linux everything went smoothly.

Perhaps it would be safer to change my OS to linux but actually i need to develop for windows. I need to find balanced way ;)